# can't add currency format to the total input in a sum of inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, currency

Here is my question: I need to sum 3 inputs and then they need to appear displayed in a fourth input of "total". The value of all these inputs must be formatted as currency.

In the code that I attached, the sum is done well, and I get to format the 3 first inputs but not the total input

Could someone have some idea of how to do it? how can I add format to the total input?

Thanks! take care!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
form input {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
form input.error {
    border-color: #ff0000;  
}
form label.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

label {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex input {
    max-width: 300px;
    flex: 1 1 300px;
}
.flex .currency {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    color: #999;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 0;
    line-height: 2.5;
    border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
    background: white;
}
</style>

<script>
    


    (function($, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    // When ready.
    $(function() {
        
        var $form = $( "#form" );
        var $input = $form.find( "input" );

        $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) { //a function when the user presses then releases a keyboard key.
            
            
            //When user select text in the document, also abort.
            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if ( selection !== '' ) {
                return;
            }
            
            // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
            if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
                return;
            }
            
            
            var $this = $( this );  
            
            //Retrieve the value from the input.
            var input = $this.val();
            
            var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); //Sanitize the value using RegEx by removing unnecessary characters such as spaces, underscores, dashes, and letters.
                    input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0; // function to make sure the value is an integer (a round number).

                    $this.val( function() {
                        return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "de-DE" ); //Add the thousand separator with the toLocaleString() function, then pass the sanitised value back to the input element.
                    } );
        } );
        
        /**
         * ==================================
         * When Form Submitted
         * ==================================
         */
        $form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            
            var $this = $( this );  
            var arr = $this.serializeArray();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[i].value = arr[i].value.replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''); 
            };
            
            console.log( arr );
            
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        
    });
})(jQuery);

     function sumar() { // input sum

  var total = 0;

  $(".monto").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

   var $this = $( this );
    var input = $this.val();

    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); //Sanitize the value again so that the sum can be made

    input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;


    total += input; //Sum input and put it in total variable

 

   

    }

  });

  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('amount').value = total; //  deliver the total value to the input "id=amount" 

}








</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
 
    <label>Valor #1</label> <br>
 <div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
 </div>
<br>

<label>Valor #2</label><br>
<div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
</div>
<br>

<label>Valor #3</label> <br>
<div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
</div> <br>
    <label for="amount">Enter amount</label>
    <div class="flex">
        <span class="currency">$</span>
        <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" maxlength="15" />
    </div>

</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any difference in formatting? Can you be more specific about what issue you're having?

Comment: sorry for not being so specific, the format I look for is the currency, that is, the total input has the thousand separator

for example if value 1 = 1000 value 2 = 2000 value3 = 2000
The total value is 4.000 but with the thousand separator

 it is still confusing?

Comment: You used this pice of code for the inputs but apparently forgot to add to the total: `input.toLocaleString( "de-DE" ); //Add the thousand separator with the toLocaleString() function, then pass the sanitised value back to the input element.`

Comment: Thank you! I add this code when calling my input amount and it worked! "document.getElementById ('amount'). value = total.toLocaleString (" de-DE ");"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format the value of the total input with:

`document.getElementById('amount').value = total.toLocaleString( "de-DE" );`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
form input {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
form input.error {
    border-color: #ff0000;  
}
form label.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

label {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex input {
    max-width: 300px;
    flex: 1 1 300px;
}
.flex .currency {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    color: #999;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 0;
    line-height: 2.5;
    border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
    background: white;
}
</style>

<script>
    


    (function($, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    // When ready.
    $(function() {
        
        var $form = $( "#form" );
        var $input = $form.find( "input" );

        $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) { //a function when the user presses then releases a keyboard key.
            
            
            //When user select text in the document, also abort.
            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if ( selection !== '' ) {
                return;
            }
            
            // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
            if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
                return;
            }
            
            
            var $this = $( this );  
            
            //Retrieve the value from the input.
            var input = $this.val();
            
            var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); //Sanitize the value using RegEx by removing unnecessary characters such as spaces, underscores, dashes, and letters.
                    input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0; // function to make sure the value is an integer (a round number).

                    $this.val( function() {
                        return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "de-DE" ); //Add the thousand separator with the toLocaleString() function, then pass the sanitised value back to the input element.
                    } );
        } );
        
        /**
         * ==================================
         * When Form Submitted
         * ==================================
         */
        $form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            
            var $this = $( this );  
            var arr = $this.serializeArray();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[i].value = arr[i].value.replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''); 
            };
            
            console.log( arr );
            
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        
    });
})(jQuery);

     function sumar() { // input sum

  var total = 0;

  $(".monto").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

   var $this = $( this );
    var input = $this.val();

    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); //Sanitize the value again so that the sum can be made

    input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;


    total += input; //Sum input and put it in total variable

 

   

    }

  });

  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('amount').value = total.toLocaleString( "de-DE" ); //  deliver the total value to the input "id=amount" 

}








</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
 
    <label>Valor #1</label> <br>
 <div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
 </div>
<br>

<label>Valor #2</label><br>
<div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
</div>
<br>

<label>Valor #3</label> <br>
<div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
</div> <br>
    <label for="amount">Enter amount</label>
    <div class="flex">
        <span class="currency">$</span>
        <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" maxlength="15" />
    </div>

</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked! I'm a beginner in javascript so thank you very much for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

I add this code when calling my input amount and it worked! "document.getElementById ('amount'). value = total.toLocaleString (" de-DE ");" thank you everyone

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    
    html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
*, 
*:before, 
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
form {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 60px auto;
}
form input {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    color: #666;
    border-radius: 0 7px 7px 0;
    font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
}
form input:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
form input.error {
    border-color: #ff0000;  
}
form label.error {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 11px;
}

label {
    color: #999;
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em
}
.flex {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}
.flex input {
    max-width: 300px;
    flex: 1 1 300px;
}
.flex .currency {
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 0 10px 0 20px;
    color: #999;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 0;
    line-height: 2.5;
    border-radius: 7px 0 0 7px;
    background: white;
}
</style>

<script>
    


    (function($, undefined) {

    "use strict";

    // When ready.
    $(function() {
        
        var $form = $( "#form" );
        var $input = $form.find( "input" );

        $input.on( "keyup", function( event ) { //a function when the user presses then releases a keyboard key.
            
            
            //When user select text in the document, also abort.
            var selection = window.getSelection().toString();
            if ( selection !== '' ) {
                return;
            }
            
            // When the arrow keys are pressed, abort.
            if ( $.inArray( event.keyCode, [38,40,37,39] ) !== -1 ) {
                return;
            }
            
            
            var $this = $( this );  
            
            //Retrieve the value from the input.
            var input = $this.val();
            
            var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); //Sanitize the value using RegEx by removing unnecessary characters such as spaces, underscores, dashes, and letters.
                    input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0; // function to make sure the value is an integer (a round number).

                    $this.val( function() {
                        return ( input === 0 ) ? "" : input.toLocaleString( "de-DE" ); //Add the thousand separator with the toLocaleString() function, then pass the sanitised value back to the input element.
                    } );
        } );
        
        /**
         * ==================================
         * When Form Submitted
         * ==================================
         */
        $form.on( "submit", function( event ) {
            
            var $this = $( this );  
            var arr = $this.serializeArray();
        
            for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    arr[i].value = arr[i].value.replace(/[($)\s\._\-]+/g, ''); 
            };
            
            console.log( arr );
            
            event.preventDefault();
        });
        
    });
})(jQuery);

     function sumar() { // input sum

  var total = 0;

  $(".monto").each(function() {

    if (isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val()))) {

      total += 0;

    } else {

   var $this = $( this );
    var input = $this.val();

    var input = input.replace(/[\D\s\._\-]+/g, ""); //Sanitize the value again so that the sum can be made

    input = input ? parseInt( input, 10 ) : 0;


    total += input; //Sum input and put it in total variable

 

   

    }

  });

  //alert(total);
  document.getElementById('amount').value = total.toLocaleString( "de-DE" ); //  deliver the total value to the input "id=amount" 

}








</script>

</head>
<body>

<form id="form" method="post" action="">
 
    <label>Valor #1</label> <br>
 <div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_1" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
 </div>
<br>

<label>Valor #2</label><br>
<div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_2" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
</div>
<br>

<label>Valor #3</label> <br>
<div class="flex">
     <span class="currency">$</span>
    <input type="text" id="txt_campo_3" class="monto" onkeyup="sumar();">
</div> <br>
    <label for="amount">Total amount</label>
    <div class="flex">
        <span class="currency">$</span>
        <input id="amount" name="amount" type="text" maxlength="15" />
    </div>

</form>




</body>
</html>
```